# why i got very small values in y-axis with seaborn Kdeplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, histogram, seaborn, kde-plasma

I am using Python Seaborn package to plot the kde of both original and sampled data. The issue is that the values in the y-axis is very small with multiple zeros. Is it possible to normalized the values or make it look more elegant?.

My implementation:

```
ax=sns.kdeplot(old_d,shade=True,label='Original kde')
ax=sns.kdeplot(new_d,shade=True, label='Sampled kde')
plt.legend(prop={'size': 12})
ax.set_xlabel('CPU time (in microsecond)',size=16)
ax.set_ylabel('Probability',size=16)
plt.show()
```

Example of this code,

[image]

Comment: The density function is normalized. Therefore you get those small values. You could decide to plot milliseconds instead of microseconds; that would get rid of three zeros in the density. (Also, the label is wrong, it's "Probability density", not "Probability.)

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I learnt two new things now. I am just wondering if this plot called kde? or density function? just to be clear

Comment: To make the output graph more elegant, make your y-axis with log scale. Try this: plt.semilogy(x,y).

Comment: It is a lineplot of a kernel density estimate (KDE). The result of a KDE is a probability density function (PDF).

Comment: is it okay to call the graph a kernel density estimate (KDE)? or that would be wrong